# Can't send outgoing mail to another domain on iredmail

Tags: iredmail

```
sudo tail /var/log/maillog
Oct  3 06:39:28 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 64274 exit status 1
Oct  3 06:39:28 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 06:39:54 instance-23 postfix/qmgr[63681]: warning: problem talking to service rewrite: Connection timed out
Oct  3 06:40:25 instance-23 postfix/postscreen[64336]: fatal: myhostname and relayhost parameter settings must not be identical: mail.duchi.net
Oct  3 06:40:26 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/postscreen pid 64336 exit status 1
Oct  3 06:40:26 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/postscreen: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 06:40:28 instance-23 postfix/trivial-rewrite[64337]: fatal: myhostname and relayhost parameter settings must not be identical: mail.duchi.net
Oct  3 06:40:29 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 64337 exit status 1
Oct  3 06:40:29 instance-23 postfix/master[63679]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/trivial-rewrite: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct  3 06:40:55 instance-23 postfix/qmgr[63681]: warning: problem talking to service rewrite: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Well, you can fix the obvious errors about your config (`myhostname and relayhost parameter settings must not be identical`), but a timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. Most probably your hoster is blocking outgoing SMTP connections, a common practice. Talk to your hoster.

Comment: we work on port 465

Comment: You have no influence on that. If the target server only accepts connections on port 25 you have to use it.

Comment: it's google cloud and blocked 25, we try on port 587

Answer (score 0):

Firewall configuration required for a mail server or mail transfer agent (mta) should be as follows;

- 25, 465, 587 for SMTP
- 110, 995 for POP
- 143, 993 for IMAP
- 53 for DNS,

You can check the above ports with a port control web page you can find from the Internet.

Also, if you can specify the operating system, I can help you define a firewall.